# Summation of uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble with this question.

Let $X$ be any set (could be uncountable). Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{x \in X}|f(x)|$ is convergent.

Let $$M=\sup\left\{\sum_{x \in A}|f(x)| : A \subseteq X \text{ and $A$ finite}\right\}$$

I want to show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ the set $$X_n = \left\{x \in X : |f(x)| \ge \frac1n\right\}$$ has at most $nM$ cardinality.

I used mathematical induction on $n$ but I feel that it does not work with me.

Also, is it true that : $$\left\{ x \in X :|f(x)|>0\right\} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*} X_n$$

Appreaciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $|X_n|>nM$   ($|X_n|$ possibly infinite)

Let $Y\ \subset X_n$ where $|Y|=\lfloor nM\rfloor+1$

Then $\sum\limits_{x\in Y} |f(x)| \geq \sum\limits_{x\in Y}1/n > nM/n=M$ which is absurd because of the definition of $M$.

And yes it is true that $$\left\{ x \in X :|f(x)|>0\right\} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*} X_n$$